# Is there a way to have a single member of a struct hold one out of different struct types?

Tags: c, struct, member

I am working on some code that writes output to different streams/files depending on which function of the family is called by the user. I am trying to do this as succinctly as possible and not have a ton of unused information in the struct I'm using to call the actual write function. Currently I have this as a basic structure (this is just a rough draft):

```
typedef int (*Write_Out) (char *src, size_t len);

typedef struct  s_vas_info
{
    char **ret;
    int prev_size;
}               t_vas_info;

typedef struct  s_vd_info
{
    int fd;
}               t_vd_info;

typedef struct  s_vf_info
{
    FILE *fp;
}               t_vf_info;

typedef struct  s_vsn_info
{
    size_t size;
    char * restrict str;
}               t_vsn_info;

typedef struct  s_writer
{
    int curr;
    Write_Out ft_write;
}               t_writer;
```

Where Write_Out will point to the function that sends output to the right destination, t_writer will hold all information to do this and the other structs are used when the corresponding function is called. Now I'd really like for the s_writer type to have one more member that contains one of the other struct types (directly if possible, I'm not looking to solve this with pointers and casts if at all avoidable). I am pretty new at this so I don't know if this is possible (either with these or other data types). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Lookup the `union` keyword. Thatc allows to have one item than can hold one of many different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you want a `union`.

A `union` is similar to a `struct` except that it only holds one if its members at any given time.

```
typedef struct  s_writer
{
    int curr;
    Write_Out ft_write;
    int active;
    union {
        struct {
            char **vas_ret;
            int vas_prev_size;
        };    
        struct {
            int vd_fd;
        };    
        struct {
            FILE *vf_fp;
        };    
        struct {
            size_t vsn_size;
            char * restrict vsn_str;
        };    
    };
} t_writer;
```

You can use the `active` field to determine which union field contains the actual data.  Also note that the union and its internal structs have no name, so their members can be accessed directly as members of `t_writer`;

Comment: _"so their members can be accessed directly as members of t_writer;"_ Hey, didn't know that! Interesting. Of course as long as the members do not have the same in different structs of the union.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That's why I added prefixes to the member names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, using the [`union`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) keyword.

You'd get something like that :

```cpp
typedef struct  s_mystruct
{
    union
    {
        t_writer    writer;
        t_vsn_info  vsn_info;
        t_vf_info   vf_info;
        t_vd_info   vd_info;
        t_vas_info  vas_info;
    }               u_type;
}               t_mystruct;
```

Comment: Yes, I had deleted the comment for that reason, however I thought that "single member" referred to having only one member to represent different types, not the "only member". You might need another member to define the data type anyway. (To clarify, I had commented that the outer `struct` was unnecessary)